# how to get the post ID from wp_insert_post

Tags: functions

I am programatically inserting a new page, then I want to use the ID of that new page to add a template, however wp_insert_post isn't returning me any ID, here's the code I am using

```php
$tittle = 'My new page';
$newPage = array(
        'post_type'     => 'page',
        'post_title'    => $tittle,
        'post_status'   => 'publish'
    );
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $newPage);
print_r($post_id);
```

in reallity I use the code this way

```php
function criar_pag($titulo, $template = 0){
    $a = get_page_by_title( $titulo, 'post' );
    if ($a == null || $a->post_status == 'trash') {
        $pagina = array(
            'post_type'     => 'page',
            'post_title'    => $titulo,
            'post_status'   => 'publish'
        );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $pagina);
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', $template);
    }
}
criar_pag("my new page", "customtemplate.php");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested your code in a function hooked on `wp_body_open` and it works:

```
add_action( 'wp_body_open', 'function_test' );
function function_test() {
    $tittle = 'My new page';
    $newPage = array(
        'post_type'     => 'page',
        'post_title'    => $tittle,
        'post_status'   => 'publish'
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $newPage);
    print_r($post_id);
}
```

Where do you use this code ?

Comment: Hi, and thanks, I had update the answer with the inteire function, I had notice the $post_id doesnt return, thats why the template isnt be inserted

Comment: your code even without the add_action it works for me also, but my function inside my function it doesnt, let me check this...

Comment: Where do you use your functions?
Maybe you launch it to early. On which hook ?

Comment: I have to agree with @SébastienSerre here - it's probably because you're running it on the wrong action-hook. I've never seen the "criar_pag" before - you should really use WordPress' core hooks instead.